# Format date without changing data type to varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

Today I was working with SQL and I was creating view in sql server , come to know that after convertng and formatting date time value dd-mm-yyyy date data type get changed

So my quest is , is there any way to convert or format date in dd-mm-yyyy without changing data type of column of view in sql server

Comment: This question does not make sense -- I'm sure you were not changing the data type of the column, you were changing the data type of your select statement.  If you don't want to change that just leave it as it -- how it is desplayed depends on what the local display program is -- what are you using to display the values.

Comment: Formatting is for displaying. The datatype of the column doesn't change when you format the output. As such, dates don't have a format. At least not one that is very useful. It is actually stored internally as a decimal.

Comment: Please to create a view in sql server and convert or format the value of date data type and check you will see the view column data type get changed to nvarchar . I did hence I asked the quest if you want I will add the screenshot

Comment: Thanks! @Sean, I know but is there any way that we can format without changing data type

Comment: @NikVarma you can change the regional settings of your sql server so the date will be displayed in the default format you want.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Whenever you start formatting any datatype in any language the output of the format is a string. I have a feeling you are wanting a certain date format in your application but need to keep sorting and filtering working correctly. This is why formatting should ALWAYS be done on the client side and not the database.

Comment: We r migrating oracle to other db and in middle layer we are using sql view , we don’t want that end db get stuck while inserting data. Any way thanks! @Sean Just looking for solution

Comment: Then stick with the datatime datatype. I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: just run `SET DATEFORMAT DMY` in the same transaction and data will be formatted as you need.

Comment: In oracle date have format dd-mm-yyyy with data type date and in sql we have data type nvarchar In sql view after formatting to required and end db have column with data type date

Answer (score 2):

A SQL Server `date` data type is a 4-byte binary structure without a displayable format. It is the client application that formats the value for presentation purposes.

In T-SQL, you'll need to convert the value into a string with the desired format. The application will then display that value as the formatted string.

Comment: Consider the example of reading the data with a C# program, then you would not want to convert the value to a string -- if you did all kinds of things would not work right (eg sorting).

Comment: @Hogan, the SQL `date` type will be returned as a .NET `DateTime` structure. The C# app could convert that into the formatted string for display, like `sqldate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`, instead of in T-SQL.

Comment: Yes that was my point.  You don't want to convert it to a string in that case as you stated in your answer.